# how to connect Android Application to server database

Tags: android, mysql

I have just completed my android application tutorial but i don't know how applications are connected to server database. Which language is used or so?

Comment: please provide additional information like: Which tutorial link, What you need to do with the application. What kind of database are you trying to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want connect your android to `MySQL` server.

In order to have connection between `Android` and `MySQL` server, you need to write a php script.  PHP script then connects  your `MySQL` database to perform the operation.

You may refer [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) and [this](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-mysql-tutorial-to-perform-basic-crud-operation/).

These two articles helped me a lot in my project and I hope they help you too.